# Iterating through multiple values for one dict key in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is an extract from one of my python functions:

```
d = {'ANIMAL' : ['CAT','DOG','FISH','HEDGEHOG']}
d_list = []
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    temp = [key, value]
    d_list.append(temp)
```

When I print `d_list` it currently gives me:

```
>>>print d_list
[['ANIMAL', ['CAT', 'DOG', 'FISH', 'HEDGEHOG']]]
```

How do I rewrite the function so it gives me:

```
>>>print d_list
[['ANIMAL', 'CAT'],['ANIMAL', 'DOG'],['ANIMAL', 'FISH'],['ANIMAL', 'HEDGEHOG']]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two nested loops can do this easily -

```
d = {'ANIMAL' : ['CAT','DOG','FISH','HEDGEHOG']}
d_list = []
for key, values in d.iteritems():
    for value in values:
        d_list.append([key, value])
```

Using list comprehension -

```
d_list = [[k,v] for k, values in d.iteritems() for v in values]
```

For python 3.x, you should change `iteritems` to `items`

Comment: Why didn't I think to use list comprehension.  It might be worth noting that `iteritems` has changed to `items` in python 3.

Comment: Thanks Sierr, I have added that in my answer

Comment: Your comment just made me realize I forgot the letter 'a' in the first part of my name. I just fixed it... LoL

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. I would iterate over the value's of the key directly.

```
d = {'ANIMAL' : ['CAT','DOG','FISH','HEDGEHOG']}

d_list = []

for value in d['ANIMAL']:
    temp = ['ANIMAL',value]
    d_list.append(temp)

print (d_list)
```

Result:

```
[['ANIMAL', 'CAT'], ['ANIMAL', 'DOG'], ['ANIMAL', 'FISH'], ['ANIMAL', 'HEDGEHOG']]
```

Comment: Your code is correct for test data. But it is better to do code so that it works for multiple entries in dictionary

Comment: @Kuro: True. However the OP didn't ask about multiple uses. I only answered with the simplest solution I could think of for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second loop:

```
d = {'ANIMAL' : ['CAT','DOG','FISH','HEDGEHOG']}
d_list = []

for key, values in d.iteritems():
    for value in values:
            temp_list=[key, value]
            d_list.append(temp)
```